# Optional field in avro schema are not working

Tags: java, avro

I am trying to use optional field in avro message. I am using avro 1.8.2.

If the optional field is missing in the JSON message then it doesn't work and throws following exception.

**org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected field name not found: username**

You can reproduce the issue with below files.

**Step :1** -> Create a json file (test.json) - Here field username is missing in the JSON file

```
{
   "tweet":"Simple message.",
   "timestamp":7866844999
}
```

**Step :2** -> Create a schema file (schema.avsc) - Here username is declared as optional field

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"test_schema",
   "namespace":"com.test.avro",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"username",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "string"
         ],
         "default":null,
         "doc":"doc 1"
      },
      {
         "name":"tweet",
         "type":"string",
         "doc":"doc 2"
      },
      {
         "name":"timestamp",
         "type":"long",
         "doc":"doc 3"
      }
   ],
   "doc:":"A basic schema"
}
```

**Step 3** - Run this command - (You need to download avro-tools jar)

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar fromjson --schema-file schema.avsc test.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Avro defaults are only applicable at consumption/reading, not when serializing or writing Avro

Therefore, you need

```
{
   "tweet":"Simple message.",
   "username": null, 
   "timestamp":7866844999
}
```

Or actually add a real username since tweets should have them, anyway

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, Avro defaults are only guaranteed to be applied when reading _using schema resolution_.  When you have an writer schema and a evolved reader schema, defaults are used to provide the values for any new fields.

Comment: The defaults are still only resolved by the reader schema, for all fields. Evolved or not